# Gitlab Runner in Docker

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

How do I set the number of unicorn workers for Gitlab Runner, when using the official Docker image? Or do I have to run multiple runners, since I am using Docker images, that shouldn't be that bad (I think?)

Is it possible to do it while starting Gitlab-Runner?
Below is the command I am using to start the runner:

```
docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always \
  -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

I added gitlab.rb with

```
 unicorn['worker_processes'] = 3
 unicorn['worker_timeout'] = 60
```

to /srv/gitlab-runner/config, stopped and destroyed it with

```
docker stop gitlab-runner && docker rm gitlab-runner
```

And restarted it with the command above, but it still refuses to run jobs concurrently

EDIT:
Looks like I found a **different** solution for this. (That's still not an answer to the question above)
Using the above command to start the Runner, I changed `concurrent = 1` to what I want in `/srv/gitlab-runner/config/config.toml` and that works perfectly.

I first thought the autoscaling option could be a thing, but looks like I misunderstood the concept behind it. Didn't think it would actually create new Droplets (in DigitalOcean), I rather thought it would create new Runner as needed.

For more advanced options see https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html